# Feature request: Provide search room option in chat mobile version

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

The mobile version of chat does not have a search option:

> [image]

And `all` contains 1406 pages.

Please provide a search option in the top bar (like the filter rooms search bar on full site).